# How to get parameters through mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been searching for a long time now with no success, and I am almost there. However, I need to create this rule:

```
www.webpage.com/index.php?variable=x
```

to

```
www.webpage.com/x and www.webpage.com/x/
```

So far I have this code in .htaccess:

```
^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?nombre=$1 [L]
```

and what it helps me is in putting getting what I need but with .html

```
www.webpage.com/x.html
```

and I need

```
www.webpage.com/x
```

Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using mod_rewrite, try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?nombre=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Excelent! That did the trick! Thank you very much Jon Lin.. :D